# Como criar uma requisição http em c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou querendo enviar sms através dessa url;

```
https://www.iagentesms.com.br/webservices/http.php?metodo=envio
&usuario=iagente
&senha=12345
&celular=5199999999
&mensagem=teste+integracao+http
```

Mas não sei como fazer essa chamada.
Meu código:

```
public static void EnviarSmsOnly(string celular, string mensagem)
    {
        if (celular != null || mensagem != null)
        {
            string endereco = "https://www.iagentesms.com.br/webservices/http.php?metodo=envio";
            string usuario = "&usuario=user";
            string senha = "&senha=senha";
            string celularSoNumero = Util.RemoveNaoNumericos(celular);
            string destinatario = "&celular=" + celularSoNumero;
            string msg = "&mensagem=" + mensagem;
            string url = endereco + usuario + senha + destinatario + msg ;
            //Aqui já não sei fazer.
            WebRequest requisicao = WebRequest.Create(url); ;
            requisicao.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            requisicao.Method = "GET";
            requisicao.GetResponseAsync();
        }

    }
```

Site da API: https://www.iagente.com.br/api/sms .
Grato desde já.

Comment: Não acontece nada? Tem algum erro? Existe algum tutorial para essa requisição, configuração, site etc...

Comment: Nao acontece nada @VirgilioNovic, segue o tutorial: https://www.iagente.com.br/api/sms

Comment: dê uma olhada neste exemplo, creio que irá te auxiliar. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Segui o tutorial mas deu erro. "Falha na autenticação porque o participante remoto fechou o fluxo de transporte."
Linha 102:                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Comment: Tem erro na autenticação, ou seja, erro local de dificil reprodução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz o exemplo abaixo, pegando o retorno do servidor.
Está retornando uma mensagem de erro de credencial, provavelmente, tens que se cadastrar e usar as credenciais fornecidas pelo serviço para fazer um teste com retorno real.

Foi alterado o retorno do método de **void** para **string**, como pode ver no código.

```
public static string EnviarSmsOnly(string celular, string mensagem)
        {
            if (celular != null || mensagem != null)
            {
                string url = $"https://www.iagentesms.com.br/webservices/http.php?metodo=envio&usuario=iagente&senha=12345&celular={celular}&mensagem={mensagem}";

                var requisicao = WebRequest.Create(url);

                // Pega o stream com o contendo retornado pelo servidor.
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)requisicao.GetResponse();
                var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                // Abre o stream usando o StreamReader.
                var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                // Lê o conteudo para retornar o que aconteceu.
                return $"Status: {response.StatusDescription}; Response: {reader.ReadToEnd()}";
            }

            return "Número ou mensagem não informados.";
        }
```

Abaixo, exemplo de como chamar o método:

```
var response = EnviarSmsOnly("5199999999", "ola mundo");
```

Caso esteja usando uma aplicação **Console** para testes, pode imprimir o resultado no **Prompt** usando o método **Console.WriteLine()**, se exemplo abaixo:

```
var response = EnviarSmsOnly("5199999999", "ola mundo");
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

**EDIT:**

Encontrei essa biblioteca [IAgenteSmsSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/IAgenteSmsSharp), acho que pode te ajudar a fazer o que deseja.

Comment: Não testei ainda, porém com a biblioteca já valeu muito. Obrigado.